# How to handle environment variables on a deployed SF4 application

Tags: symfony, deployment, 12factor

Symfony introduced a new Dotenv component since Symfony 3 which allows us to handle environment variables as application parameters. This looks really nice and it's the best practice to follow according to [12factor app manifesto](https://12factor.net/config).

Now, regarding Symfony 4 they went further by pushing forward this practice and that's why I started using environment variables via the *.env* file.

And then I wanted to deploy and I realized that the *.env* file must not be persisted on the server as it would be the same as having a *parameters.yml* file.

So I've been digging into the documentation a bit and I found [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/master/configuration/external_parameters.html#configuring-environment-variables-in-production) which explains that we can directly create environment variables via some webserver directives. That's great for code being executed via FPM but it does not tell us how to handle environment variables when running a command via the CLI for instance.

How can I achieve this ?
Should there be an equivalent of a *.env* file stored somewhere? But then parameters would be duplicated ?

I'm welcoming any help ;)

Comment: take a look into https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

Answer (score 0):

Finally had the time to check [the link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) **Neodan** posted and everything is in there!

So for those of you wondering what to do, simply edit the */etc/environment* file and add your variables. Then reboot your server and all your processes will have access to these variables.

I guess that's the simplest solution. The only drawback of this method is that these variables are available by any process / users but that's ok as far as I'm concerned.

If you want a more *secure* solution I suppose that you could, as I stated before, configure your webserver to add environment variables and export them via your *.bash_profile* or *.bashrc* file but be careful about how you start your shell (when deploying your application for instance). It's more complicated to maintain and prone to errors I'd say.

*N.B.: You also might want to be careful about how you name your variables to prevent collisions.*